# Unsure why this takes two clicks to work

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm unsure why this script I found takes two clicks to work.?
I have an anchor within a div that, when clicked is supposed, to animated the parent div down, yet it seems to take two clicks on that link to work. It's most likely a silly problem but I don't write code I'm just a designer.

Thank you

```
var clicked = false

$('.anchor').click(function () {
    if (clicked == true) {
        $(".div").animate({ top: '0px' }, 600);
        clicked = false;
    } else {
        $(".div").animate({ top: '-90px' }, 600);
        clicked = true;
    }
});
```

The HTML:

```
<header class="div">
    <div>
      some stuff in here
    </div>
    <a href="anchor"></a>
</header>
```

The div class is the header at the top of the page which is off canvas, which then slides down when the anchor is clicked.

Comment: added the html, sorry, I'm new

Comment: @user3433539 You're selecting on ".div" in your jquery selector, but "." is what you prepend when you're selecting a class. You should remove the dot (this won't fix the problem though, probably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two issues in your code:

1.) Your forgot the semicolon at the beginning of your script

`var clicked = false` `;` is missing

2.) You are targeting `.anchor`, bur in your html your target has no class like this, just a href, you need:

`<a href="#" class="anchor">click</a>`

And like cbayram said, you should change `var clicked = false;` to `var clicked = true;`

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cKM2f/2/)

Comment: thank you so much for this, it works perfectly! I'm signing up to treehouse next month so I can learn JS and jQuery. Thank you Sebsemillia and everyone who took the time to help!

Answer (score 1):

Add `clicked = true;` to your js at the first line in the `click` function

From your code:

```
var clicked = false

$('.anchor').click(function () {
    clicked = true;
    if (clicked == true) {
        $(".div").animate({
            top: '0px'
        }, 600);

        clicked = false;
    } else {
        $(".div").animate({
            top: '-90vh'
        }, 600);
        clicked = true;
    }

});
```

Because `.click()` only fires when `.anchor` is clicked.

It took two clicks before because,at first click it executed `else` block which set `clicked=true;`. So in the second click, `clicked` is `true`, so it executed the `if` block.

Comment: Right, Amit this will always run as clicked=true

Comment: this seems to work but the header will not slide back up now, thank you

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xzP7W/)

Your default state is the same as that of the first animation's result. Hence you have to click twice. Change your default state:

```
var clicked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `$('.anchor').click(function(){` .. function places?

Is it inside the function called? if yes, move it outside the called function.

Else, you can use bind a click event or use jQuery live events.